# JS parse string always as string and no number evaluation

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
var garbage = JSON.parse('12345E666');
```

=> infinity
while

```
var garbage = JSON.parse('1234E300');
```

=> 1.234e+303

As you can see, this is rather rotten and definitely not what I want.

The task at hand is to receive a string ... and it should remain as such. 
I have looked at JSON.stringify already, but this is also not what I want:

=> "\"1234E300\"".
Additional clean-up is required and it is always a mess to do this afterwards.

JSON.parse accepts an additional parameter, but from what I have seen, this is also not elegant.

```
var garbage1 = JSON.parse('1234E300', function(key, value){return value;});
var garbage2 = JSON.parse('1234E300', function(key, value){return value;});
```

Well ... see for yourself. It is rotten.

How do I prevent JS to be smart and interpret something out of a string that it should not do?

Input (String) => Output (Value) ... and no messing around with the data that should not be there.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want a String why use `JSON.parse()`? You could just do `let string = '1234E300';`.

Comment: Do you need this function? `f(x) => x`

Comment: *"The task at hand is to receive a string ... and it should remain as such."* Then don't use `JSON.parse` on it. Or if you really, really want to use `JSON.parse` for some reason, use the JSON for a string (`JSON.parse('"12345E666"')`) instead of the JSON for a number. But it doesn't make sense to do that.

Comment: @leonheess Really, I do not know. This is something that I will have to face next week on work. Legacy code, not done by me. There may have been idea behind it, but I do not know what it may have been. I was wondering about this myself, why it is necessary to interpret it in such a way, but maybe there are some aspects in which it may prove to be useful. I cannot provide details outside that it is used in a ts file.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see my comment to leonheess. Legacy code. And it does work most of the time, but not always. That is why I am here. I am not a JS-Developer and this is not my realm of expertise. I need a solution for this problem. Maybe I do need the function or maybe I do not. From the likes of it, it seems that I can bypass it, but the entire structure appears embedded in a more complex structure of cause ... so, things may not be as easy as it seems.

Generally speaking, I am looking for a way to handle this issue without having to change too much of the old legacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is a string, if you `JSON.stringify` it, `"` quotes will be put around the serialized string (along with any other necessary escaping), after which it can be `JSON.parsed` back into a string without any clean-up:

```js
const serializeAndDeserialize = (str) => {
  const json = JSON.stringify(str);
  console.log(json);
  const originalString = JSON.parse(json);
  console.log(originalString);
};

serializeAndDeserialize('12345E666');
serializeAndDeserialize('1234E300');
```

Comment: This may be an option. I may have to run some tests against this with some proper data on Monday and see whether this would deal with all problems, but at least in case nothing would be broken.

I will accept this answer for now.